# Increase price depending in product variation (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce

Is it possible to make a product variation change the price?

For example I have a basic product and variants of it:

```
Quantity
-- 10
-- 20
-- 50

Color
-- Blue
-- Red

Project
-- Yes
-- No
```

I have prices for quantities, no matter for what color. But I would like to increase the price if you check "Project - Yes" and don´t change anything, when you select "Project - No".

Answer (score 0):

That can be done on your product data settings.

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

in this image, variation #23, I have set the price to 20. Then on #360, I've set the price to 40.

This just means, [Color Black][Project - Yes] combination will have a price of 20. And [Color Black][Project - any other values] will have a price of 40. Try to play around with the prices on Variations.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nXPfhXg.png
<br>
This is my situation. Each #variant have price, for. ex. 20, 40, 60.<br>
I would like to set if "Zamawiam projekt" check "Yes" system increase price +150.

Comment: create that combination... the same with my example.. I have two `Black`, one for `yes` and other for `no`. `Green` has only one, which is `yes`. I can add  another one for `no`... with different prices depending on the combination...

Comment: use that settings dropdown, so you can add combination like `[10][Blue][No]` with price of 20. Then add variation, `[10][Blue][Yes]` set price 170.

Comment: if color is not a factor for pricing, you can combine like `[10][any..][No]` price 20. `[10][any..][yes]` price 170. `[20][any..][No]` price 40. `[20][any..][yes]` price 190. `[50][any..][No]` price 60. `[50][any..][yes]` price 210.

Comment: I know I can do like this. I have many products, some with a lot of variants. I would avoid editing so many options. No option to set variant "Project"-"Yes" always increase price regardless other options.

Comment: Let's wait for anyone to answer with code. I don't have anything in mind right now that can do this other than  that. I will try to look.

Comment: Is Project a 'Used for variations' attribute, i.e., are you generating a slice of variations in the Cartesian product for each value of Project?